# 301 redirect from non-www to www version

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my non-www site to its www version, to this end I put the below code in the `.htaccess` in root folder of my site:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

But problem is that after all this configuration I get this error when trying to access it:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly

Both www and non-www address of my site doesn't work.

Is anything wrong with that code?

Comment: If you remove that code, does either the site work OK (either www or non-www)? There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. Are you using a CMS of some kind that also redirects? Check the network traffic in the browser, what redirects do you see?

Answer (score 0):

This situation arises on a server that hosts multiple domains. Mostly such servers are shared hosts or reseller type of hosting arrangements. Use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

[I've found the solution here](http://techwelkin.com/redirect-www-to-non-www-url-htaccess-wordpress)

Comment: This code does the opposite of what you are asking in the question, and redirects from www to non-www. (?) Whether this is necessary (or even works) depends on how the "multiple domains" are implemented. But you made no mention of _multiple domains_ in your question? And even if you had multiple domains, the code in your question alone shouldn't have resulted in that error. But the `www` version of the site should have still worked? So, I think there is something more to this question than it first appears...?